# Adding a directive to the last element in ng-repeat and then animate it with ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have a certain problem when building a list inside a directive with Angular. I'm adding pages to the array and displaying them on the site through ng-repeat. I want to animate the last page that comes to the site, but things get complicated when I also want to add another directive to the last element only.

I built this simpler demo of what I'm trying to achieve in Plunker:
[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/UzlQL4WY8q5ZEPBEVEiW)

This is my template for displaying pages:

```
<div>
    <button ng-click='addPage()'>Add</button>
    <div class='page' ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
        <div ng-if='!$last' class="page">{{page.content}}</div>
        <div ng-if='$last' class="page" page-offset>{{page.content}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it always animates the last two elements (because after adding the new one it changes both of them). I want to add the directive on the last one and also animate the last element only.

Any advice on how to solve this and make it work would be very much appreciated! So thank you all for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

It was a problem with the css classes that I used in the directive template (I renamed .page to .content). I updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UzlQL4WY8q5ZEPBEVEiW) and now everything works as it should :) All those years and I'm still not able to go pass those 'noob' mistakes from time to time :D

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `page-offset` directive to a class type. Something similar to as shown below.

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
.directive('pageOffset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C', // It will restrict your directive to a class
    templateUrl: 'page-offset.html'
  };
});
```

Then in your `ng-repeat` you can conditionally apply the class using `ng-attr-class` by checking whether it's the last element. Here 'page page-offset' class will be applied to the last element and just 'page' class will be applied to the other elements.

```
<div>
    <button ng-click='addPage()'>Add page</button>
    <div class='page' ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
        <div ng-attr-class="{{$last && 'page page-offset' || 'page'}}">{{page.content}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ttk5LxTHYIJTSZfh3mHd?p=preview).

Comment: Hey thank you for your help, not exactly what I was looking for in my case, because I need my directive as an attribute so I can pass some additional parameters to it. But with your answer I learnt a new approach that will sure prove useful in the future. In my case above it was a 'noob' mistake... problem with css classes... :) updated PLUNKER and now it works as I need it to work. But still thnx for your help again!